# VersionError: No matching document found for id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm having hard time with mongoose. I want to fetch a document from one collection and want to save it to different collection immediately. But I'm facing version error.

I tried removing the __v property, but still I get the same error.
Below is my code. It's part of huge  function, so posting only relevant code.

```
//appointment-schema.js  
const mongoose = require("mongoose");   
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;  
const AppointmentSchema = new Schema({  
providerId: { type: String, index: true },  
providerName: { type: String, index: true },  
date: {type: Date},  
slotsPerHour:{type: String},  
allAppointments :{ type: Array }  
},{ timestamps: true });    


module.exports = {
Appointment: AppointmentSchema
};


//appointment.js
let criteria = { "providerId": req.providerId,
     "date": req.date
    }
var res = await this.db.Appointment.findOne(criteria); // I want to save this response to different collection
console.log("res :"+res);    

await this.db.AppointmentLog.create(res);// here, I'm getting an error

// AppointmentLog-schema.js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const AppointmentLogSchema = new Schema({
providerId: { type: String, index: true },
providerName: { type: String, index: true },
date: {type: Date},
slotsPerHour:{type: String},
allAppointments :{ type: Array }
},{ timestamps: true, strict : false });

module.exports = {
AppointmentLogSchema
};





/* console.log("res :"+res)
res :{ allAppointments:
[ { serialNo: 0, slots: [Array] },
{ hour: 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z, serialNo: 5, slots: [Array] } ],
_id: 5c30c82eb632745b14b20452,
providerId: 'D02AT029527F0374',
date: 2019-01-05T18:30:00.000Z,
providerName: 'Dr. Ray Smith',
createdAt: 2019-01-05T15:07:26.177Z,
updatedAt: 2019-01-06T06:38:31.215Z } */
```

Here, I do not see the __v property of the document.  Earlier I had used *delete doc.__v* to delete the version key.
Below is the error :

> VersionError: No matching document found for id "5c30c82eb632745b14b20452"   version 0 modifiedPaths "allAppointments, _id, providerId, date, providerName, createdAt, updatedAt"

I'm not sure whether I'm doing something wrong that is not allowed by mongoose or is this problem with mongo version(I'm using 3.6.9).

Comment: Are you trying to save the find result from Appointment to AppointmentLog? Then in that case, store res._doc inside the doc variable and then try the same code. Delete the _id,__v variables from the doc as well.

Comment: @FirozShams  Actully it was res not doc, sorry for that. I edited it. Also, I'm trying delete res._id; But it is not deleting the _id

Comment: Mongoose doesn't directly allow you to delete properties from documents that are default or have been defined in the model. If you want to delete it, use delete res._doc._id

Comment: @FirozShams Yes, I could delete _id and__v and it is working as expected now. I was doing delete res._id instead of delete res._doc._id Thank you very much. You made my day

Comment: Glad I could help

Comment: @VilasD. Can you write an answer?